# Can I create additional keyboard shortcuts inside xkbconfig that switch to a particular language, instead of cycling?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

My current keyboard config is quite complex, but the relevant line is:

```
setxkbmap -option -option 'grp:rshift_toggle, compose:rctrl' dmru,ru,ua &
```

Rshift now cycles through dmru, ru, and ua. When my screen gets locked, I have no way of knowing which layout am I using to type my password, and in general it would be awesome to have a shortcut which takes me back to english. (dmru in this case, it's a custom layout.) I can't run setxkbmap $language at every switch because it breaks my xcape and xmodmap settings; running them every time takes a couple of seconds and is not practical.

Would it be possible to switch to a particular language, without running setxkbmap every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group-switch options operate with 4 keysyms: `ISO_First_Group`, `ISO_Last_Group`, `ISO_Next_Group`, and `ISO_Prev_Group`.  The option you use, `grp:rshift_toggle`, only provides `ISO_Next_Group`, so cycling through the layouts is all you're seeing.

The behavior you're looking for (select a specific layout) exists on the `ISO_First_Group` or `ISO_Last_Group` keysyms.  You want to find an existing (or write a new) option that supplies at least one of those keysyms.

Looking quickly through `man xkeyboard-config`, these existing options appear to include `ISO_First_Group`:

- `grp:shift_caps_switch`: *Caps Lock to first layout; Shift+Caps Lock to last layout*
- `grp:win_menu_switch`: *Left Win to first layout; Right Win/Menu to last layout*
- `grp:lctrl_rctrl_switch`: *Left Ctrl to first layout; Right Ctrl to last layout*
- `grp:lctrl_lwin_rctrl_menu`: *Left Ctrl+Left Win to first layout; Right Ctrl+Menu to second layout*

These options are defined in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/group`.  One of them may be acceptable for your use.  If they don't provide exactly what you want, you can use the definitions to tailor your keymap to your needs.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't know similar options can be combined, two group-switches in my case.

Comment: you do have to watch out for conflicts with other options -- the `grp:lctrl_rctrl_switch` option would conflict with your `compose:rctrl` option, and whichever you applied last would overwrite the other.